# How to run scapy using WireShark Portable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, pcap, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to run [Whos on my network](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/whos-on-my-network) in Python3.8 windows 10 platform.
I install Winpcap, copied its root folder to another place, uninstalled winpcap and copied its root folder back to the my_programs folder(I meant I tried using Wincap as a portable software).
And here is what i tried:

```
from whos_on_my_network import __main__ as hmm
hmm.current()
```

But scapy raises the error:

```
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Interface is invalid (no pcap match found) !
```

So how do I run the program with a portable sniffer( ie.,Wireshark )?

Comment: What interface are you specifying for scapy?

Comment: Need a portable one